# Расчет параметров по формулам и внедрение рабочих кнопок расчета и обновления

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton

Есть приложение с кнопками, а также графы для ввода-вывода данных и две формулы (см. рис 1) для расчета значений вероятности.

После ввода входных данных расчет не происходит по нажатию кнопки "Расчет" и сброс входных данных.

Код:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import math

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1005, 630)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1005, 630))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextOnly)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -70, 811, 611))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ббпла.PNG"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 90, 261, 161))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(250, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.261364 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.698864 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255))")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 10, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 70, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 190, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 250, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 310, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 370, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 320, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 380, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 490, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_6.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_6.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_6.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 550, 701, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 490, 701, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 550, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_10.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_10.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_10.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_10.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 0, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_11.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_11.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 60, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_12.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_12.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_12.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 120, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_13.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_13.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_13.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 180, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_14.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_14.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_14.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 240, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_15.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_15.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_15.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 300, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_16.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_16.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_16.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 370, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_17.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_17.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_17.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 561, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 430, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 440, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.lineEdit_18 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 430, 71, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_18.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_18.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_18.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_18.setObjectName("lineEdit_18")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 480, 621, 121))
        self.label_16.setText("")
        self.label_16.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../белый фон.PNG"))
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 480, 621, 121))
        self.label_17.setText("")
        self.label_17.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../белый фон.PNG"))
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 0, 621, 121))
        self.label_18.setText("")
        self.label_18.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../белый фон.PNG"))
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 120, 621, 121))
        self.label_19.setText("")
        self.label_19.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../белый фон.PNG"))
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 240, 621, 121))
        self.label_20.setText("")
        self.label_20.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../белый фон.PNG"))
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 360, 621, 121))
        self.label_21.setText("")
        self.label_21.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../белый фон.PNG"))
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, -20, 271, 451))
        self.label_22.setText("")
        self.label_22.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../красный фон.PNG"))
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.label_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 180, 701, 451))
        self.label_23.setText("")
        self.label_23.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../красный фон.PNG"))
        self.label_23.setObjectName("label_23")
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 701, 451))
        self.label_24.setText("")
        self.label_24.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../красный фон.PNG"))
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.label_25 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_25.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(810, 190, 271, 451))
        self.label_25.setText("")
        self.label_25.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../красный фон.PNG"))
        self.label_25.setObjectName("label_25")
        self.label_27 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_27.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 80, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.label_27.setFont(font)
        self.label_27.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_27.setObjectName("label_27")
        self.label_28 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_28.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 140, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.label_28.setFont(font)
        self.label_28.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_28.setObjectName("label_28")
        self.label_29 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_29.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 190, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.label_29.setFont(font)
        self.label_29.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_29.setObjectName("label_29")
        self.label_30 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_30.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 320, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.label_30.setFont(font)
        self.label_30.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_30.setObjectName("label_30")
        self.label_31 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_31.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 390, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.label_31.setFont(font)
        self.label_31.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_31.setObjectName("label_31")
        self.label_32 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_32.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 450, 16, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.label_32.setFont(font)
        self.label_32.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_32.setObjectName("label_32")
        self.label_26 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_26.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 150, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_26.setFont(font)
        self.label_26.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_26.setObjectName("label_26")
        self.label_33 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_33.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 130, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_33.setFont(font)
        self.label_33.setObjectName("label_33")
        self.label_34 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_34.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 40, 561, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_34.setFont(font)
        self.label_34.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.UpArrowCursor))
        self.label_34.setObjectName("label_34")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 490, 201, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type AU")
        font.setPointSize(41)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(250, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.261364 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.698864 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255))")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_25.raise_()
        self.label_22.raise_()
        self.label_23.raise_()
        self.label_24.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.label_21.raise_()
        self.label_20.raise_()
        self.label_19.raise_()
        self.label_18.raise_()
        self.label_17.raise_()
        self.label_16.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.label_14.raise_()
        self.label_13.raise_()
        self.label_12.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_6.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_10.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_17.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.label_11.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_18.raise_()
        self.label_15.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_15.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_16.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_14.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_13.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_12.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_11.raise_()
        self.label_27.raise_()
        self.label_28.raise_()
        self.label_29.raise_()
        self.label_30.raise_()
        self.label_31.raise_()
        self.label_32.raise_()
        self.label_26.raise_()
        self.label_33.raise_()
        self.label_34.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1005, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет вероятности "))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "РАСЧЁТ"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "N ="))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "V ="))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "L ="))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "q ="))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "T   ="))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "T   ="))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "расп."))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "возд."))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вероятность 2 (P2)="))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вероятность 1 (P1)="))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вероятность "))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "T   ="))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обн."))
        self.label_27.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "м/с"))
        self.label_28.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "м"))
        self.label_29.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "км"))
        self.label_30.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "с"))
        self.label_31.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "с"))
        self.label_32.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "с"))
        self.label_26.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "крит."))
        self.label_33.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D   ="))
        self.label_34.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОБНОВИТЬ"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calc)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_all)

    def clear_all(self):
            self.lineEdit_11.clear()
            self.lineEdit_12.clear()
            self.lineEdit_13.clear()
            self.lineEdit_14.clear()
            self.lineEdit_15.clear()
            self.lineEdit_16.clear()
            self.lineEdit_17.clear()
            self.lineEdit_18.clear()
            
            self.lineEdit_10.clear()
            self.lineEdit_6.clear()

    def calc(self):
        N = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        V = self.lineEdit_12.text()
        D = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        L = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        q = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        Trasp = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        Tvozd = self.lineEdit_17.text()
        Tobn = self.lineEdit_18.text()
        
        if not N or not V or not D or not L or not q or not Trasp or not Tvozd or not Tobn:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(None,
                                          'Внимание',
                                          'Заполните все поля ввода.'
                                          )
            return

        try:
            N = float(N)
            V = float(V)
            D = float(D)
            L = float(L)
            q = float(q)
            Trasp = float(Trasp)
            Tvozd = float(Tvozd)
            Tobn = float(Tobn)
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(None,
                                          'Внимание',
                                          f'Заполните правильно поля ввода \n {e}.'
                                          )
            return

        if V == 0 or N == 0 or L == 0 or q == 0 or  Trasp == 0 or  Tvozd == 0 or  Tobn == 0:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(None,
                                          'Внимание',
                                          'division by zero.'
                                          )
            return

        P1 = self._R(k, q)
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(f'{P1:.3f}')

        P2 = self._Pp(R, b)
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{P2:.3f}')

        P1 = self._P1(q, Trasp, Tvozd, Tobn, N, L, V)
        P2 = self._P2(P1)

    def _P1(self, q, Trasp, Tvozd, Tobn, N, L, V):
        op1 = Trasp + Tvozd + Tobn
        op2 = 1 / op1
        op3 = (N * V) / L
        op4 = ((q * op1)/(q * op1 + op3))**N 
        return op4

    def _P2(self, P1):
        op1 = 1 - P1
        return op1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Формулы:

[image: ФОРМУЛЫ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск приложения делается так:

```
import sys
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()

    w = MainWindow()                                    # <----
    w.show()                                            # <----
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

а дальше исправляйте ошибки, которые у вас есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]